# Pass char from string to function

Tags: c

I'm trying to translate some text to *morse alphabet*. When I send a single letter to function it works properly but I want to make it write a word so I'm trying to send words one by one with an index of pointer but it doesn't happen please help.

---

**tree struct:**

```
typedef struct tree
{
    char *letter;
    char *morscode;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
} tree;
```

---

**Functions:**

```
tree *root=NULL;

void add (char* letter, char* morscode) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (tree *)malloc(sizeof(tree));
        root->letter   = letter;
        root->morscode = morscode;
        root->left     = NULL;
        root->right    = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        tree *new = (tree *)malloc(sizeof(tree));
        new->letter   = letter;
        new->morscode = morscode;
        new->left     = NULL;
        new->right    = NULL;

        tree *node = root, 
             *mom;
        while (node != NULL) {
            mom = node;
            if (strcmp(letter, dugum->letter) == -1)
                node = node->left;
            else 
                node = node->right;
        }
        if (strcmp(letter, mom->letter) == -1) 
            mom->right = new;
        else 
            mom->right = new; 
    }
}

tree *searchbyletter(char& letter, agac *node) {

    if(strcmp(letter,node->letter) == -1)
        searchbyletter(letter, node->left);
    else if(strcmp(letter, node->letter) == 1)
        searchbyletter(letter, node->right);
    else
        return node;
}

void write(char *letter) {
    int x = strlen(letter),
        i;
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("%s", searchbyletter(letter[i], root)->morscode);    
    }
}

void preorder(tree *node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        printf(" %s ", node->letter);
        preorder(node->left);
        preorder(node->right);
    }
}

void inorder(tree *node) {
    if (node != NULL) {
        inorder(node->left);
        printf(" %s ", node->letter);
        inorder(node->right);
    }
}

void postorder(tree *node) {
    if (node!=NULL) {
        postorder(node->left);
        postorder(node->right);
        printf(" %s ", node->letter);
    }
}
```

---

**main:** [I initialized morse codes and letters manually.]

```
void main() {
    char* arr[27][2] = {
        {" ", " "}, {"E", "."}, 
        {"T", "-"}, {"I", ".."}, 
        {"A", ".-"}, {"N", "-."},
        {"M", "--"}, {"S", "..."}, 
        {"U", "..-"}, {"R", ".-."}, 
        {"W", ".--"}, {"D", "-.."},
        {"K", "-.-"}, {"G", "--."}, 
        {"O", "---"}, {"H", "...."}, 
        {"V", "...-"}, {"F", "..-."},
        {"L", ".-.."}, {"P", ".--."}, 
        {"J", ".---"}, {"B", "-..."}, 
        {"X", "-..-"}, {"C", "-.-."},
        {"Y", "-.--"}, {"Z", "--.."}, 
        {"Q", "--.-"}
    };
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        add(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);  
    }
    preorder(kok);
    printf("\n");
    inorder(kok);
    printf("\n");
    postorder(kok);
    printf("\n");
    write("HELLO WORLD");
}
```

Comment: Please show input, actual output, expected output, relevant data structures, and layout your code clearly.

Comment: It also looks like you're using an overly complicated structure to represent what should essentially be a simple lookup table mapping characters to strings.  i.e. `const char* morsecode[256] = { ... }`

Comment: What makes you thing `arr[27][2]` is sufficient to hold, e.g. `{"H", "...."}`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has completely changed the meaning of the question and now none of the posted answers make sense. I see no way to salvage this.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem is with using `strcmp` function to compare single characters (for example, `strcmp(letter,node->letter)`).

This function (`strcmp`) compares null-terminated C strings, so in your case when you try to compare letter "B" it will actually compare string "BA".

You can compare characters with `==` operator like this:

`if(letter == node->letter)`

But of course, without complete code snippet it is hard to tell.

Comment: I uploaded the full code i didnt do it first because im translating it from turkish,anyway i think the problem is it's not taking letter one by one i'm sending a word and it should parse it

Comment: As I said, you should not use strcmp this way to compare single letters. You should use regular operators (such as ==, <, >) to do the comparison. See this code as an example: https://ideone.com/cHyHLi

Answer (score -1):

Your array type is needlessly obfuscated. What you should do is to create a table where the letters save as the index.

For this to be possible, you need to ensure that your system uses a sane symbol table. This is the case for all mainstream systems (ASCII, UTF8 etc). If you worry about obsolete crap like EBCDIC, you can add this to the code: `_Static_assert('Z'-'A' == 25, "Dysfunctional symbol tables not supported");`

Once it is established that `'A'` to `'Z'` are adjacent, you can simply do this:

```
#define TABLE_SIZE ('Z'-'A' + 1)
#define INDEX(ch) (ch-'A')        // convert from ASCII to a number 0 to 25

const char* MORSE [TABLE_SIZE] =
{
  [INDEX('A')] = ".-",
  [INDEX('B')] = "-...",
  ...
};
```

The above is the same as writing `const char* MORSE [TABLE_SIZE] = { ".-", ... }`, but the *designated initializers* couple each letter to a Morse code. `INDEX('A')` evaluates to `0`, since we want the first string pointed at from index zero in the array.

Then decode like this:

```
const char str[] = "HELLO";
for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
{
  printf("%s\t", MORSE[ INDEX(str[i]) ] );
}
```

This only supports capital letters and no spaces, but you get the idea.

Comment: array is not the point i had to do it with bts. that's why college is needed i think

Comment: @YasinCoşkun That was not in the original question. You can't just go and completely change the meaning of the question then whine on answers that were posted before the change.

Comment: that was the first time i posted something . also you didnt replied when it was still original anyway it doesnt matter.I dont care what you think.I'm just new to coding